# Digital ocean / virtual server with temporary URL

Tags: unix, digital-ocean

Lets say I am working on a new version of a site - and I want to build it in a digital ocean droplet --- but I can't point the Domain name over there until everything is finished. How can make a place-holding URL? I have 10 small sites in one droplet currently --- so I would have thought http://104.236.110.45/respective-site would have worked...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subdomain and have nginx serve the new version of the site via a new `server` config on that subomain only.